# How to enable/disable Bootstrap buttons remotely using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using Bootstrap for my project. Basically I want to have the Button disabled ("disabled" class) until the Click Count reaches a distinct number.
JS Part:

```
 var timesClicked = 0; //main click variable
 var CPC = 5;
 var up1cost = 100; //cost for upgrade 1


function btnClick(){
 timesClicked = timesClicked + CPC; //increases clicks by 1  
 $("#timesClicked").html(timesClicked) //parses over via jquery
 if(timesClicked <= up1cost){
    $("#up1btn").addClass("disabled")
        } else {
    $("#up1btn").removeClass("disabled")
        }   
     return true; 
     }
```

Optional HTML Part:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" id="up1bt">Purchase: C100</a></p>
```

Any help?

Comment: who is invoking `btnClick`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake `up1btn` and `up1bt` - The button id is `up1bt` but your selector is `#up1btn`, change the button id to `up1btn`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9MgAK/)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: @Alyn I also took quite some time

Comment: @ArunPJohny Nice one =)